# Python class--Super variable

Tags: python

The below piece of code is giving me a error for some reason, Can someone tell me what would be the problem..

Basically, I create 2 classes Point & Circle..THe circle is trying to inherit the Point class.

```
Code:


class Point():

    x = 0.0
    y = 0.0

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print("Point constructor")

    def ToString(self):
        return "{X:" + str(self.x) + ",Y:" + str(self.y) + "}"

class Circle(Point):
    radius = 0.0

    def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
        super(Point,self).__init__(x,y)
        self.radius = radius
        print("Circle constructor")

    def ToString(self):
        return super().ToString() + \
               ",{RADIUS=" + str(self.radius) + "}"


if __name__=='__main__':
        newpoint = Point(10,20)
        newcircle = Circle(10,20,0)
```

Error:

```
C:\Python27>python Point.py
Point constructor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Point.py", line 29, in <module>
    newcircle = Circle(10,20,0)
  File "Point.py", line 18, in __init__
    super().__init__(x,y)
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: Did you make some edits to the source? Did your `init` call look like that originally?

Comment: `ToString`, oh! my (pythonic) eyes are bleeding

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you already may have fixed the original error, which was caused by `super().__init__(x,y)` as the error message indicates, although your fix was slightly incorrect, instead of `super(Point, self)` from the `Circle` class you should use `super(Circle, self)`.

Note that there is another place that calls `super()` incorrectly, inside of `Circle`'s `ToString()` method:

```
        return super().ToString() + \
               ",{RADIUS=" + str(self.radius) + "}"
```

This is valid code on Python 3, but on Python 2 `super()` requires arguments, rewrite this as the following:

```
        return super(Circle, self).ToString() + \
               ",{RADIUS=" + str(self.radius) + "}"
```

I would also recommend getting rid of the line continuation, see the [Maximum Line Length section of PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) for the recommended way of fixing this.

Comment: The error message explicitly states the error is *not* coming from that line.

Comment: @MarkRansom - Right you are!  Thanks.

Comment: you should recommend that `ToString()` is not (at all) the correct think to do, that's what `__str__` is for.

Answer (score 7):

`super(..)` takes only new-style classes. To fix it, extend Point class from `object`. Like this:

```
class Point(object):
```

Also the correct way of using super(..) is like:

```
super(Circle,self).__init__(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Point(object):

x = 0.0
y = 0.0

def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    print("Point constructor")

def ToString(self):
    return "{X:" + str(self.x) + ",Y:" + str(self.y) + "}"

class Circle(Point,object):
radius = 0.0

def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
    super(Circle,self).__init__(x,y)
    self.radius = radius
    print("Circle constructor")

def ToString(self):
    return super(Circle, self).ToString() + \
           ",{RADIUS=" + str(self.radius) + "}"


if __name__=='__main__':     
    newpoint = Point(10,20)    
    newcircle = Circle(10,20,0)
```