# Extending a new-style class

Tags: python, class

I'd like to add some extra attributes to the `pyTree` `node` class for implementing a decision tree algorithm.

It has only one `data` attribute for user defined contents, which is also the attribute searched when using the class method `getNode(content)`. I am thinking to store a unique ID there, but also store other attributes for tree calculations.

I've tried doing various things, but it appears from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838596/python-class-super-variable), that the following should be the way to do it:

```
from pyTree.Tree import Tree 

class decTree(Tree):
    def __init__(self, val1, val2, data=None, children=None,):
        super(decTree, self).__init__(data=None, children=None)
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = decTree(val1=1.5, val2='string', data='567')
```

Which results in the following attribute error:

```
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Any suggestions on doing this or other things to consider with the implementation would be great. Thanks!

Comment: What is the **full** traceback of the exception? Clearly the `TypeError` doesn't stem from your use of `super()` here, you have it two arguments.

Comment: `pyTree` requires Python 3 or newer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `pyTree` on Python 2; but the project only works on Python 3.

From the [PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyTree):

> A list-derived TREE data structure in **Python 3**

`super()` in Python 3 takes no arguments when used in a method, and [that's what the `pyTree` project does](https://github.com/yoyzhou/pyTree/blob/master/src/pyTree/Tree.py#L55-L56). This makes the codebase incompatible with Python 2.

You were otherwise correctly extending the class; your code works when used with Python 3.